# Erro ao tentar inserir dados em um banco

Tags: php, mysqli

Tenho as seguintes funções:

```
function query($stmt){
    try{
        return mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
    finally{
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        mysqli_close($GLOBALS['conexao']);
    }
}

function cadastrarNoBanco($nome, $email){
    $ip = getIp();
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($GLOBALS['conexao'], "INSERT INTO tbl_lead VALUES(default, ?, ?, ?, default)");
    return query(mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $nome, $email, $ip));
}
```

Mas está dando o seguinte erro ao chamar a `cadastrarNoBanco()`:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given

Já tentei passar o `stmt` por referência, mas não funciona. Pensei que fosse um erro na sintaxe da query, mas caso eu a execute direto no MySql, ela passa de boa.

Comment: Não passe `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` como parâmetro. Ele retorna um booleano, não o stmt. Na verdade essa função recebe o stmt por referência e o modifica, então chame essa função separadamente e passe o stmt direto como parâmetro de `query`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Funcionou! Quer fazer uma resposta para isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função mysqli_stmt_bind_param() retorna um boolean.

Você deve executa-la, sem atribuir a ninguém e depois passar o $stmt para a função query. Ex:

```php
function cadastrarNoBanco($nome, $email){
    $ip = getIp();
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($GLOBALS['conexao'], "INSERT INTO tbl_lead VALUES(default, ?, ?, ?, default)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $nome, $email, $ip)
    return query($stmt);
}
```

Sugestão: Dê uma olhada no PDO ela é a opção mais recomendada para trabalhar com banco de dados quando são se usa um ORM.
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php